Expressing interior product locally
If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $\omega = \omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_k}$ a $k$-form, where the sum is over indices $1\le i_1<\dots<i_k\le n$, then for a vector field $X=X^{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}$ the interior product $\iota_X\omega$ is a $(k-1)$-form defined by $$\iota_X\omega=\omega(X,-,\dots,-).$$ Now since its a $(k-1)$-form locally $\iota_X\omega$ can written as
$$
\iota_X\omega=(\iota_X\omega)_{i_1,\dots,i_{k-1}}dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_{k-1}}
$$
where
$$
(\iota_X\omega)_{i_1,\dots,i_{k-1}}=\omega\left(X^{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_1}}, \dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_{k-1}}}\right) = X^{j}\omega_{j,i_1,\dots,i_{k-1}}.
$$
So
$$
\iota_X\omega = X^{j}\omega_{j,i_1,\dots,i_{k-1}}dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_{k-1}}.
$$
However, in Wikipedia they state
$$
\iota _{X}(dx^{i_1}\wedge ...\wedge dx^{i_k})=(-1)^{j-1}X^{j}dx^{i_1}\wedge ...\wedge {\widehat {dx^{j}}}\wedge ...\wedge dx^{i_k}.
$$
So using linearity this would give
$$
\iota_X\omega =  X^{j}\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k}(-1)^{j-1}dx^{i_1}\wedge ...\wedge {\widehat {dx^{j}}}\wedge ...\wedge dx^{i_k}
$$
and these two don't seem to be equal, what gives?

I think Wikipedia is right. Hint:
$$
X=X^1\partial_{x^1}+X^2\partial_{x^2}
$$
$$
\omega=\omega_{12},dx^1\wedge dx^2=\omega_{12},dx^1\otimes dx^2-\omega_{12},dx^2\otimes dx^1
$$
$$
i_X\omega=X^1\omega_{12},dx^2-X^2\omega_{12},dx^1
$$
